# REGEXP_SUBSTR in Teradata

Tags: regex, teradata, regexp-substr

I am having data in a column like XXX/XXXX/XXXX/XYYUX/YYY. I am trying to extract only the first two digits after the 3rd backslash(/) in the column which is 'XY' in this example. Can you please help?
Thanks!

Comment: Try [`(?:[^\/]+\/){3}(\d{2})`](https://regex101.com/r/0NQtl7/1)

Comment: (?:[^\/]+\/){6}(\w{2})..this worked..thanks!

Comment: I am still trying to work on the syntax..I tried REGEXP_SUBSTR (Column_Name,?:[^\/]+\/){6}(\w{2})AS TEST and it did not work..Can you please help?

Comment: There's an undocumented variant of REGEXP_SUBSTR, which allows specifying which capturing group to return: `RegExp_Substr_gpl(s, '(.*?/){3}(..)',1,1,'i',2)`, but TD14 has some differences, then `RegExp_Substr_gpl(s, '(?:.*?/){3}(..)',1,1,'i',1)` might work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    REGEXP_SUBSTR('XXX/XXXX/XXXX/XYYUX/YYY','^([^/]*/){3}\K..',1,1,'i')


'^' start of string
'([^/]*/){3}' looks for 0 or more non-slashes followed by a slash, 3 times
'\K' match reset operator drops the part of the string that has been matched up to this point
'..' grabs the next two characters in the string
```

Comment: I didn't know that Teradata supports `\K`
, nice.

Comment: Hi , apologies first if I need to start a new thread...  I got a problem very similar - am having data in a column word1/word2///word3/word4/word5  the length for each word and overall length are vary.I am trying to extract the whole word between n th and n+1th /,  Can you please help? Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Try using -  STRTOK('/88/209/89/132]', ' /]', 3)

returns the 3rd octet, '89'