# REGEXP_SUBSTR_GPL is unlisted, and I'm unclear on what parameters it takes. Why would you use it over REGEXP_SUBSTR?

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, teradata-sql-assistant

I am trying to break down an ex-employee's code at work, which uses a series of regex expressions in Teradata SQL Assistant to extract data from strings.

They mainly lean on the loop of:

```
WHEN (WHEN REGEXP_INSTR(source, pattern, 1, 1, 0 , 'i')(INT)) > 0
THEN
    (REGEXP_SUBSTR_GPL(source, pattern, 1, 1, 'i', 1) (FLOAT))
```

I'm trying to make sense of what this is doing, but I don't understand how `REGEX_SUBSTR_GPL` works. I tried looking it up and it's apparently undocumented. I'm pretty new to MySQL, so I was wondering if somebody could help me understand what it was doing, and why someone would use it over `REGEXP_SUBSTR()`.

Additionally, is there a command within MySQL which would let me find more information about functions this like, and more information about what parameters they take?

Thank you.

Comment: If it's undocumented then it's also unsupported. I'd consider starting from the root of the problem (extracting data from strings) and starting again.

Comment: REGEXP_SUBSTR_GPL(source, pattern, 1, 1, 'i', 1) differsonly on the last int and that indicates which group it should take. see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49619100/regexp-substr-in-teradata

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful! To be clear is a capture group a grouping within the regex expression itself? I did some googling and found a possible example: ‘[a-zA-Z]\w+@\w+\.\w+‘ being divided like ([a-zA-Z]\w+)(@)(\w+)(\.)(\w+) into five groups 1.  ([a-zA-Z]\w+) 2. (@) 3. (\w+) 4. (\.) 5.0 (\w+)

Comment: I figured it out the rest of the way. I put the answer up myself, if anybody is interested in seeing it. Thank you for your help everyone!

Answer (score 1):

With help from nbk in the comments, we have an answer!

The basic format of REGEXP_SUBSTR is:
`REGEX_SUBSTR(source, pattern, start position, occurrence, matchOption)`

For REGEXP_SUBSTR_GPL it is:
`REGEX_SUBSTR_GPL(source, pattern, start position, occurrence, matchOption, subexp, RETURN0)`

The subexpression option lets you, instead of returning the result of the entire regex expression, to choose which subgroup you would like to return. Each subgroup is denoted by a set of parentheses. So for `'([a-zA-Z]\w+)(@)(\w+)(\.)(\w+)'` we have the following subgroups:

1. `'([a-zA-Z]\w+)'`
2. `'(@)'`
3. `'(\w+)'`
4. `'(\.)'`
5. `'(\w+)'`

When you set `subexp` equal to `0`, it treats the function the same way as REGEXP_SUBSTR. When you set it equal to anything above zero, it instead returns the corresponding subgroup, if it exists.

See the following example

```
SELECT 'abc123@google.com' as text
,REGEXP_SUBSTR(text,'([a-zA-Z]\w+)(@)(\w+)(\.)(\w+)', 1, 1, 'i') as REGEXP_1
,REGEXP_SUBSTR_GPL(text,'([a-zA-Z]\w+)(@)(\w+)(\.)(\w+)',1,1,'i',0) as REGEXP_GPL_1
,REGEXP_SUBSTR_GPL(text,'([a-zA-Z]\w+)(@)(\w+)(\.)(\w+)',1,1,'i',1) as REGEXP_GPL_2
,REGEXP_SUBSTR_GPL(text,'([a-zA-Z]\w+)(@)(\w+)(\.)(\w+)',1,1,'i',2) as REGEXP_GPL_3
,REGEXP_SUBSTR_GPL(text,'([a-zA-Z]\w+)(@)(\w+)(\.)(\w+)',1,1,'i',3) as REGEXP_GPL_4
,REGEXP_SUBSTR_GPL(text,'([a-zA-Z]\w+)(@)(\w+)(\.)(\w+)',1,1,'i',4) as REGEXP_GPL_5
,REGEXP_SUBSTR_GPL(text,'([a-zA-Z]\w+)(@)(\w+)(\.)(\w+)',1,1,'i',5) as REGEXP_GPL_6
```

This results in the following answer set:

| text | REGEXP_1 | REGEXP_GPL_1 | REGEXP_GPL_2 | REGEXP_GPL_3 | REGEXP_GPL_4 | REGEXP_GPL_5 | REGEXP_GPL_6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc123@google.com | abc123@google.com | abc123@google.com | abc123 | @ | google | . | com |

Thank you for your help, everybody!