# Split records with complex delimiter

Tags: regex, teradata

I have an incoming record with a complex column delimiter and need to tokenize the record.
One of the delimiter characters can be part of the data.

I am looking for a regex expression.
Required to use on Teradata 16.1 with the function "REGEXP_SUBSTR".

There can max of 5 columns to tokenize.
Planing to use case statements in Teradata to tokenize the columns.
I guess regular expression for one token will do the trick.

```
Case#1: Column delimiter is ' - ' 
Sample data: On-e - tw o - thr$ee
Required output : [On-e, tw o, thr$ee]
```

My attempt : `([\S]*)\s{1}\-{1}\s{1}`

```
Case#2 : Column delimiter is '::' 
Sample data : On:e::tw:o::thr$ee 
Required output : [On:e, tw:o, thr$ee]

Case#3 : Column delimiter is ':;' 
Sample data : On:e:;tw;o:;thr$ee
Required output : [On:e, tw;o, thr$ee]
```

The above 3 cases are independent and do not occur together ie., 3 different solutions are required

Comment: `yourString.whateverSPLITfunctionEquivalentFromLanguageYouAreUsing(" - |::|:;")` ?

Comment: What language or tool are you using?

Comment: Have you tried to write the regex yourself? Try writing it and showing your attempt.

Comment: Are there any edge cases where delimiters are present when other delimiters are in play? Eg `col::1 - col:;2 - col 3`? If so please add such examples to your question. If not, please make it clear that such edge cases never happen.

Comment: If you want to return the split functionality to return the individual pieces, you probably don't want [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://docs.teradata.com/r/Teradata-Database-SQL-Functions-Operators-Expressions-and-Predicates/June-2017/Regular-Expression-Functions/REGEXP_SUBSTR) unless you're required to use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely must use RegEx for this, you could do it like in the examples shown below using capture groups.

---

**Generic example:**

```
/(?<data>.+?)($delimiter|$)/gm
```

`(?<data>.+?)`   named capture group *data*, matching:
`.` any character 
`+?` occuring between one and unlimited times

followed by

`($delimiter|$)` another capture group, matching:
`$delimiter` - replace this with regex matching your delimiter string
`|` or
`$` end of string

---

Picking up your examples:

**Case #1:**

Column delimiter is ' - '

```
/(?<data>.+?)(\s-\s|$)/gm
```

(https://regex101.com/r/qMYxAY/1)

**Case #2:**

Column delimiter is '::'

```
/(?<data>.+?)(\:\:|$)/gm
```

https://regex101.com/r/IzaAoA/1

**Case #3:**

Column delimiter is ':;'

```
(?<data>.+?)(\:\;|$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/g1MUb6/1

Comment: Sorry, i did not see your edit about this being related to Teradata when first posting this answer. It seems there is an unlisted function REGEXP_SUBSTR_GPL in Teradata that lets you select capture groups inside a regex, that might be working with my solution above:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68706625/17447478

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would use `STRTOK` to split a string on a delimiter.  But strtok can't handle a multi-character delimiter.  One moderately over-complicated approach is to replace the multiple characters of the delimiter with a single character and split on that.  For example:

```
select
strtok(oreplace(<your column>,' - ', '|'),'|',1) as one,
strtok(oreplace(somecol,' - ', '|'),'|',2) as two,
strtok(oreplace(somecol,' - ', '|'),'|',3) as three,
strtok(oreplace(<your column>,' - ', '|'),'|',4) as four,
strtok(oreplace(<your column>,' - ', '|'),'|',5) as five
```

If there are only three occurrences, like in your samples, it just returns null for the other two.